# How to dynamically create buttons on an ionic form

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I would like to dynamically create buttons in ionic.  I can't find any information on this.  I tried a couple of quick tests which failed.

```
  week = `      <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-label (click)="showDate(11)">11</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-label (click)="showDate(12)">12</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-label (click)="showDate(13)">13</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-label (click)="showDate(14)">14</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-label (click)="showDate(15)">15</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-label (click)="showDate(16)">16</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-label (click)="showDate(17)">17</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>`
  week2 = "      <ion-row><ion-col>  <ion-label (click)='showDate(11)'>11</ion-label></ion-col><ion-col>  <ion-label (click)='showDate(12)'>12</ion-label></ion-col><ion-col>  <ion-label (click)='showDate(13)'>13</ion-label></ion-col><ion-col>  <ion-label (click)='showDate(14)'>14</ion-label></ion-col><ion-col>  <ion-label (click)='showDate(15)'>15</ion-label></ion-col><ion-col>  <ion-label (click)='showDate(16)'>16</ion-label></ion-col><ion-col>  <ion-label (click)='showDate(17)>17</ion-label></ion-col></ion-row>"
```

Basically I need to create a form or page based on passed in parameters which could drastically change the layout of the form.  It would be really inefficient to make a couple of dozen pages.  It will also create a maintenance nightmare to have several if statements per button with numerous buttons that may or may not be visible.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged angular, I guess you're using it, so you can use *ngFor, like the code bellow:

```
<ion-list padding *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
        <ion-item (click)="showDate(i)">{{ i }}</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```